# What is shiny and makes people sad when it falls?

Tags: riddle, word

I live very high.

On top of the home of all dreams.

When treated right I can really gleam.

When treated wrong I'll fall.

But I'll leave even more brightness behind.

But even this will your sadness not console.

---

What am I?

Comment: At first glance looks like you are 'tears', but I hope there is something more

Comment: they don't gleam when treated right nor do they live on top of the land of dreams afaik

Comment: Answer to the title question -- a new laptop! :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Heh, I was going to say aeroplane!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you are

> **hair**.

I live very high.  On top of the home of all dreams.

> Can't get higher on a person than the top of their head.
>  Where do dreams live? Only in our minds--in our brains. Hair is on top of that.

When treated right I can really gleam.

> Well-cared-for hair, according to countless hair product commercials, is supposed to be shiny or glossy; indeed, to gleam.

When treated wrong I'll fall.

> Badly treated hair can fall out.

But I'll leave even more brightness behind.

> Losing enough hair to go fully or partially bald leaves a shiny bare scalp behind.

But even this will your sadness not console.

> Many people are sad to lose their hair.

Comment: yo got it!! Username relevant btw.

Comment: Lol.  It may amuse you to know I'm about as far from blonde as it gets.

Comment: not really though, its a pretty common lastname in some hispanic countries.

Comment: "Badly treated hair can fall out." really? Any links?

Comment: @MartinSmith  "[Harsh hairstyles or treatments: Hairstyles that consistently use rubber bands, rollers or barrettes, or pull hair into tight styles such as cornrows, can inflame and scar hair follicles. So can incorrectly used chemical products such as dyes, bleaches, straighteners or permanent wave solutions. Depending on the degree of damage, resulting hair loss can be permanent.](http://www.livescience.com/34731-hair-loss-alopecia-treatment.html)". Or the biased but concordant info at  **http://www.belgraviacentre.com/blog/links-between-hair-dye-chemicals-and-hair-loss/**

Answer (score 10):

Are you

> spectacles or glasses

I live very high

> Very high in terms of your body

On top of the home of all dreams.

> On top of eyes

When treated right I can really gleam.

> You can help get a fine vision

When treated wrong I'll fall.

> I not properly wore, specs tend to fall

But I'll leave even more brightness behind.

> Glasses will be shattered creating more reflections and/or refraction

But even this will your sadness not console

> But broken glasses won't make one happy

Comment: Quick and nice! +1

Comment: almost, this is very similar to what I had in mind. Although I think the intended solution fits a bit better. I think the third sentence is the one that doesn't quite make sense. +1 though.

Answer (score 6):

I'll probably get downvoted to oblivion, but I think you're...

> a plane.

I live very high.

On top of the home of all dreams.

> Planes are made on the ground, but spend so much more time flying that you can consider them to "live high".

When treated right I can really gleam.

When treated wrong I'll fall.

> When its maintenance is done properly and it's used correctly, you can get the best out of it (figuratively make it "gleam"), otherwise it can crash. Also, functional planes have lights that "gleam" at night.

But I'll leave even more brightness behind.

> When it crashes, it can explode.

But even this will your sadness not console.

> People (especially your relatives) dying just isn't easy to forget.

Comment: I'm not sure that planes do spend more time in the air than on the ground, once you take maintenance into account. But, still, they spend enough time in the air that I wouldn't dispute your claim that they "live high".

Answer (score 6):

Even if the answer has been given, I'll leave this interpretation of mine.

I thought about:

> Ozone

On top of the home of all dreams.

> The world, the home of all dreaming humans

When treated right I can really gleam.

> When hit by the solar wind, it glows.

When treated wrong I'll fall.

> People polluting the world will cause the ozone levels to drop

But I'll leave even more brightness behind.

> The sun rays will be even stronger without the ozone protection

But even this will your sadness not console.

> UV-A, UV-B and UV-C rays will cause cancer and other diseases, making people really sad

Comment: Loved this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> a Star?  
>  Maybe the fall is shooting star and the sadness is not consoled by even the beauty of stars

Comment: I don't think how a star is trated affects whether it falls or not.

Comment: Yes I seem to be wrong

Comment: Is it Tree? Teeth?

Comment: trees don't shine, and teeth don't live on top of the home of dreams

Answer (score 0):

A previously mentioned possibility matches exactly if viewed in a different perspective:

> a **star** on top of a Christmas tree

On top of the home of all dreams.

> a Christmas tree represents hopes, expectations and dreams that kids (and a few adults) see fulfilled on Christmas' day, whether by the act of giving or receiving. The star is placed on top of that tree, and thus on top of that "home of all dreams".

When treated right I can really gleam.

> whether a plastic star or a paper star covered in shiny confetti, it will gleam when properly illuminated.

When treated wrong I'll fall.

> if badly placed and if the tree is shaken, the star will fall.

But I'll leave even more brightness behind.

> if broken or dragged around, it will leave a shiny trail of confetti or pieces.

But even this will your sadness not console.

> you will have to clean up the mess of a broken star (or tree) and get a new one to replace it until Christmas festivities ends.

Hohoho! Happy new year!